# Indy10 - TIdContext to TIdTcpServer

Tags: delphi, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

I make different instances of `TIdTcpServer` and assign a pointer to the `Data` property that I need later on if a Client Connects/Disconnects/Executes.

Is it possible to get the "Parent" `TIdTcpServer` from a `TIdContext`?

If so, how can I do that?

Example:

```
procedure TMainWindow.OnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
 ParentServer : TIdTcpServer; 
begin
  // ParentServer := AContext... 
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type-cast the `TIdContext` to a `TIdServerContext`, then you can access its public `Server` property:

```
procedure TMainWindow.OnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  ParentServer : TIdCustomTCPServer; 
begin
  ParentServer := TIdServerContext(AContext).Server;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Quick and easy. Thank you very much.